# reading from a bufferedreader stream globaly

Tags: java, stream

so Im trying to write this class which is going to parse a file and read commands from it.

I want the ctor to just open the stream and do nothing else.
while I parse the file in other class methods.
But I'm getting a nullpointerexception when I try to read the file in the methods I made.

help will be apprecated :D

```
public class Parser {
private BufferedReader _input;
private String _command;

public Parser(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);

    BufferedReader _input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
}

public boolean hasMoreCommands() throws IOException {

    String line;
    if ( (line = _input.readLine()) != null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        _input.close();
        return false;
    }
}

public void advance() throws IOException {
    String line;
    do {
        line = _input.readLine().trim();
    } while (line.equals("") || line.substring(0,2).equals(COMMENT_SIGN)); 

    String[] splittedLine = line.split(COMMENT_SIGN);
    _command = splittedLine[0];
    _command = _command.replace(" ", ""); 
}
```

my main for testing it + the exception trace

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Parser input = null;
    input = new Parser("D:\\test.asm");
    System.out.println( input.hasMoreCommands());
```

}

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at nand6.Parser.hasMoreCommands(Parser.java:40)
at nand6.Parser.main(Parser.java:116)
```

Comment: show us the stack trace !! It will help us diagnose better

Comment: @Rohit there ,added it now

Comment: public Parser(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(_filename);
should be 
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filename);//and not _filename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this snippet of code

```
public Parser(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(_filename);

BufferedReader _input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
}
```

Change

```
BufferedReader _input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
```

to

```
_input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
```

Your mistake : You are creating another local variable of type ***BufferedReader _input*** hence your class level variable is still null resulting in a ***NullPointerException***

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically defining a new BufferedReader object called "_input" inside your constructor. You think that after calling the constructor you instantiate "_input" outside the constructor. But you are not, it refers to null. That's why you are getting NullPointerException. Just remove "BufferedReader" in front of "_input" inside your constructor, in order to refer to correct object.